# Next JS - SyntaxError when using framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, syntax, next.js, framer-motion

I'm using NextJS version 12.0.3 with framer motion for animations. Putting the functionality of the framer-motion library aside, when I tag any html element in my component, I get an error

```
error - SyntaxError: The requested module 'react' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from 'react';
const { createContext } = pkg;
```

The file (Login.jsx) causing the error:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      className=""
    >
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Oddly enough, when I am routed TO the logo page from a different page, the page loads fine. But when I REFRESH the page, I'm faced with this error.
When I keep the import statement for framer-motion, BUT remove the motion. tags on my div element, the error does not persist when I refresh.

Is this a common issue with Next JS 12.0.3?
Should I just roll back to previous versions?

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same errors by importing framer-motion.
I solved this problem change import by require:

const { motion } = require("framer-motion");

Comment: This fixed it too, but is this really the solution? There must be a way for it to work with import syntax.

Comment: Seems like theres a topic on it here - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30750 - they do esmExternals: false but I don't think that's the solution either.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from the latest update.
This works for me yarn add framer-motion@6.5.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and looking at the [upgrade guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading)
of next js I found that the I was using nodejs version < 12.22.0 which caused this issue. Upgrading it to nodejs 12.22.0 fixed the issue for me.